# How to renew Instagram token to increase api limit

Tags: javascript, api, limit, instagram

I've created a website or Instagram bot that auto likes and follows based on tags.

I've abide by Instagrams server side auth and enforced signed header and can currently like 100 images per hour and follow/unfollow 60 times an hour.

The current limit per user is 350 likes/hour, I'd like to hit close to that, around 250-300. But each access token is only worth 100/hour.

So my question is, how can I release my current access token so that I can get a new one?

The website is http://instapromobiz.com if you want to try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't avoid the hourly rate limit per user by getting a new access token for that user. You'd need to get an access token for a different user or queue up requests and make them after an hour has passed.

Comment: I'd have to disagree. The 100 like limit is per access token. The 350 like limit is per user, so if the user generates a new access token, they should be able to reach the 350 like limit. I recently stumbled upon a post that showed how to release the access token, making it possible to get a new one but I can't seem to find it again.